# How to position submit button on same line as input with Simple Form and Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

Using Simple Form and Bootstrap, I would like to have the following appear in-line instead of having the submit button below the input select.

```
<%= simple_form_for :select_rollout, :html => {:class => "form-inline"}, do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :rollout_id, collection: @rollout_options, :label => false %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Apply" %>
<% end %>
```

The following solution only works for inputs (the submit button is rendered outside the div for the inputs):

```
<%= form.input :city, label: 'City/State/Zip', input_html: {class: 'span3'}, wrapper_html: {class: 'controls controls-row'} do %>
  <%= form.input_field :city, class: 'span1' %>
  <%= form.input_field :state, class: 'span1' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve this, I needed to use **input_field** inside an input block, and use the **inline-form** style on the wrapper for the block:

```
<%= f.input :rollout_id, :label => false, wrapper_html: {class: "form-inline"} do %>
  <%= f.input_field :rollout_id, collection: @rollout_options, :label => false %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Apply", :class => "btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reading this later, I normally just wrap the input and submit in a flexbox.
You can provide styling afterwards how you want each element to look (ie: give the form-group width:100%

```
<%= simple_form_for :select_rollout, :html => {:class => "form-inline"}, do |f| %>
  <div class="flexbox-class">
    <%= f.input :rollout_id, collection: @rollout_options, :label => false %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Apply" %>
  </div>
<% end %>


.flexbox-class {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  .form-group {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .btn-primary {
    margin-bottom: 16px
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding the `pull-left` or `pull-right` class to your elements. that will add the `float: left` or `float: right` attributes to your object.

but if float isn't going to work for you, create your own class called inline like so:

`.inline {
   display: inline;
}`

or (depending on your site's implementation)

`.inline {
   display: inline-block;
}`

and add the `inline` class to your objects.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I tried them but to no avail. See below for solution.